# Working with a list of lists of dataframes with different dimensions

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I am working with a list of lists of dataframes, like so:

```
results <- list()
for( i in 1:4 ) {
  runData <- data.frame(id=i, t=1:10, value=runif(10))
  runResult <- data.frame( id=i, avgValue=mean(runData$value))  
  results <- c(results,list(list(runResult,runData)))
}
```

*The reason the data looks this way is its essentially how my actual data is generated from running simulations via clusterApply using the new parallel package in R 2.14.0, where each simulation returns a list of some summary results (runResult) and the raw data (runData)*

I would like to combine the first dataframe of the second level lists together (they are the same structure), and likewise the second dataframe of the second level lists. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652522/rbind-dataframes-in-a-list-of-lists) seemed to be the answer, however all the dataframes have the same structure.

The best method I've found so far is using `unlist` to make it a list of dataframes, where odd indices and even indices represent dataframes that need to be combined:

```
results <- unlist(results,recursive=FALSE)
allRunResults <- do.call("rbind", results[seq(1,length(results),2)])
allRunData <- do.call("rbind", results[seq(2,length(results),2)])
```

I'm certain there's a better way to do this, I just don't see it yet. Can anyone supply one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shamelessly stealing a construct from Ben Bolker's excellent answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903325/adding-all-elements-of-two-lists/7903408#7903408)...

```
Reduce(function(x,y) mapply("rbind", x,y), results)

[[1]]
  id  avgValue
1  1 0.3443166
2  2 0.6056410
3  3 0.6765076
4  4 0.4942554

[[2]]
   id  t      value
1   1  1 0.11891086
2   1  2 0.17757710
3   1  3 0.25789284    
4   1  4 0.26766182
5   1  5 0.83790204
6   1  6 0.99916116
7   1  7 0.40794841
8   1  8 0.19490817
9   1  9 0.16238479
10  1 10 0.01881849
11  2  1 0.62178443
12  2  2 0.49214165
     ........
     ........
     ........
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extract the give data frame from each piece of the list, then `rbind` them together:

```
runData <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results, '[[', 2))
runResult <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results, '[[', 1))
```

This example gives 2 data frames, but you can recombine them into a single list if you want.